# Added the most records to the new table

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create an app. So the way an app like this.
Phone numbers that order more than five times, will enter the customer table.
This is the code I tried.

```
<?php 

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bus');

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT phone_number, count(phone_number) as quantity FROM report GROUP BY phone_number ORDER BY quantity");

    while ($qq = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $quantity = $qq['quantity'];

            if ($quantity == 5 ) {
                $phone_number = $qq['phone_number'];
                $quantity = $qq['quantity'];

                $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT phone_number FROM record WHERE EXISTS (SELECT phone_number FROM customer)");
                $exe = mysqli_num_rows($sql2);

                if($exe == 1){
                    echo"<script>window.location = 'show-customer.php';</script>";
                }else{

                $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO customer (`phone_number`) VALUES ('$phone_number')");

                echo"Successful added"; 

            }
    }}
 ?>
```

Explanation of the code:

1. I counted the number of times the phone number was ordered.
2. If the phone number has been ordered five times, then I check that the phone number already exists or not on the customer table.
3. If it's there then I'll show the customer's page. If not then I will add that phone number to the customer table.

After I run my code, it only displays "Successful added" without any record in the table.
I'm really a beginner, and all the code above is my own idea.
I do not know, I made a big mistake or not in my code.
Please help, because I have to finish my final assignment in my college. :(

Comment: `$quantity=5` -> `$quantity==5`

Comment: The output of "successfully added" immediately follows the call to the insert query, so the fact that no record was inserted would imply that the call failed. You should check `$sql3`, if there was an error, and if yes, print the error message (using `msqli_error()`).

Comment: @KarstenKoop thankyouu. It works, but the phone number that orders only once also goes into the table. :( Where is the error?

Comment: see my first comment, did you correct that?

Comment: @KarstenKoop yess. And the phone number that orders only once also goes into the table. There may be a mistake in the logic. I do not have any ideas anymore. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @KarstenKoop thankyou so much for your answer Karsten. Its work now.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following `($quantity = 5 )` to `($quantity == 5 )`

Comment: It works, but the phone number that orders only once also goes into the table. :( Where is the error?

Comment: Change your if statement where it says **$quantity = 5**, because you are assigning 5 to variable $quantity, use equality operator i.e. **==**

Comment: I've changed it, but the phone number that orders only once also goes into the table. :(

Comment: Try checking the value of `$quantity = $qq['quantity'];`, use `echo  $quantity;` and see if the value is less than 5 or try truncating that table or use a different number.

Comment: Alhamdulillah, it works now. Thankyou so much Ussaid.

Comment: Glad I could help.